# Filter shipping method based on custom checkout field at checkout page

Tags: woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce WordPress plugin

Added one custom field at checkout page, called - Address Type which is drop down contains 2 values. Business/Commercial and Residential

I have total 3 shipping methods - International Flat Rate, Flat Rate, Free Shipping

Now, condition that I want when end user select residential then and then they will get all 3 shipping methods but once user select a business option then hide/remove International Flat Rate and Flat Rate shipping methods (I mean show only Free Shipping).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'add_address_type_field' );
function add_address_type_field( $fields ) {

 $address_type_field = array(
    'type'      => 'select',
    'label'     => __('Address Type', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('address-field', 'form-row-wide', 'validate-addresstype'),
    'clear'     => true,
    'options'   => array(
                    'residential'   => 'Residential',
                    'business'      => 'Business/Commercial'
                    ),
 );

 $fields['billing']['billing_address_type']   = $address_type_field;
 $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_type'] = $address_type_field;

 return $fields;
}
 add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'display_shipping_method_based_on_state', 10, 2);
 if(!function_exists('display_shipping_method_based_on_state')) {
function display_shipping_method_based_on_state($rates) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $state = WC()->customer->shipping_state;        
    $address_type = WC()->customer->shipping_address_type;        
    $free_shipping = $rates['free_shipping'];
    if($address_type == 'business')
    {
        $rates = array();
        $rates['free_shipping'] = $free_shipping;
    }
    return $rates;
}
}
```

This is my code that I am trying. Let me know where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What doesn’t work in your code?

Comment: When I am selecting a "Business/Commercial" address type on checkout page then "Flat Rate and Free Shipping" shipping methods should hide for selection with ajax call.

That I want to filter shiping methods with woocomerce filters

Comment: In WooCommerce package rate hook, I'm getting a value of all default woocommerce fields. But not getting value of my custom added field in filter (address type - function "add_address_type_field").